# Using dockerfile and Docker Compose deploy app in debian droplet, however, PostgreSQL was not found

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, digital-ocean

I followed this instruction for Docker part:
[Python CRUD Rest API using Flask, SQLAlchemy, Postgres, Docker, Docker Compose](https://dev.to/francescoxx/build-a-crud-rest-api-in-python-using-flask-sqlalchemy-postgres-docker-28lo)
tried to use Dockerfile and Docker Compose file deploy app in debian droplet not app platform because of cost consideration. however, it is succesful in local but errored in cloud. I believe it is becuase the PostgreSQL database was not found. Do I need to change URL in docker file? what's URL I should use after deployment. I thought I can use droplet's ip address <=> localhost?
Please refer files and errors below. Thanks so much.
docker compose file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  flask_app:
    container_name: flask_app
    image: dockerhub-flask_live_app:1.0.0
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      - DB_URL=postgresql://postgres:postgres123456@flask_db:5432/postgres
    depends_on:
      - flask_db
  flask_db:
    container_name: flask_db
    image: postgres:16
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres123456
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  pgdata: {}
```

docker file：

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Set environment variables for Python
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    unzip \
    wget \
    gnupg2 \
    ca-certificates \
    apt-transport-https \
    software-properties-common
# Add Google Chrome to the repositories
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'

# Install Google Chrome
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get -f install
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends google-chrome-stable

#OR
#wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
#sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
#sudo apt-get -f install -y

RUN google-chrome --version
RUN wget -q --continue -P /chromedriver "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/120.0.6099.71/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip" \
     && unzip /chromedriver/chromedriver* -d /usr/local/bin/


# Move and adjust permissions for chromedrive
# RUN wget https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/119.0.6045.105/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip
# RUN && unzip chromedriver-linux64.zip
# RUN && mv chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver /usr/bin
# RUN && chown root:root /usr/bin/chromedriver
# RUN && chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver

# Install Python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /app/
#RUN apt-get install python3-pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app/

EXPOSE 5000

ENV FLASK_APP=app.py

#CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
CMD ["gunicorn"  , "-b", "0.0.0.0:5000", "app:app"]
```

app.py

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:postgres123456@flask_db:5432/postgres'

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

from models import FlightDB,db
db.init_app(app)
```

models.py:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
db = SQLAlchemy()
class FlightDB(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    DRP_DATETIME =  db.Column(db.Text)
    ARR_DATETIME =  db.Column(db.Text)
    DEP_AIRPORT =   db.Column(db.Text)
    ARR_AIRPORT =   db.Column(db.Text)
    AIRLINE =       db.Column(db.Text)
    FLIGHTNUMBER =  db.Column(db.Text)
    PRICE =         db.Column(db.Text)
    LINK =          db.Column(db.Text)
    CREATEDDATE =   db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True),
                           server_default=func.now())
    #def __init__(self, DRP_DATETIME, ARR_DATETIME,ARR_AIRPORT, DEP_AIRPORT, AIRLINE,FLIGHTNUMBER,PRICE,LINK,CREATEDDATE):
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Flight {self.AIRLINE+self.FLIGHTNUMBER}>'
```

error message(I don't have "flight_db" in the code, it may come from some translation in sqlalchemy):

```
root@debian-s-1vcpu-512mb-10gb-nyc1-01:~/flight# docker compose up flask_app
[+] Running 2/0
 ✔ Container flask_db   Running                                                                                                      0.0s
 ✔ Container flask_app  Created                                                                                                      0.0s
Attaching to flask_app
flask_app  | [2023-12-30 21:04:38 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
flask_app  | [2023-12-30 21:04:38 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1)
flask_app  | [2023-12-30 21:04:38 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
flask_app  | [2023-12-30 21:04:38 +0000] [6] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6
flask_app  | [2023-12-30 21:08:21,445] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
flask_app  | Traceback (most recent call last):
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1969, in _exec_single_context
flask_app  |     self.dialect.do_execute(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 922, in do_execute
flask_app  |     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
flask_app  | psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "flight_db" does not exist
flask_app  | LINE 2: FROM flight_db ORDER BY flight_db."CREATEDDATE" DESC
flask_app  |              ^
flask_app  |
flask_app  |
flask_app  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
flask_app  |
flask_app  | Traceback (most recent call last):
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app
flask_app  |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request
flask_app  |     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 176, in wrapped_function
flask_app  |     return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
flask_app  |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
flask_app  |     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
flask_app  |   File "/app/app.py", line 258, in index
flask_app  |     posts = FlightDB.query.order_by(FlightDB.CREATEDDATE.desc()).all()
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2693, in all
flask_app  |     return self._iter().all()  # type: ignore
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2847, in _iter
flask_app  |     result: Union[ScalarResult[_T], Result[_T]] = self.session.execute(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2308, in execute
flask_app  |     return self._execute_internal(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2190, in _execute_internal
flask_app  |     result: Result[Any] = compile_state_cls.orm_execute_statement(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/context.py", line 293, in orm_execute_statement
flask_app  |     result = conn.execute(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1416, in execute
flask_app  |     return meth(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 516, in _execute_on_connection
flask_app  |     return connection._execute_clauseelement(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1639, in _execute_clauseelement
flask_app  |     ret = self._execute_context(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1848, in _execute_context
flask_app  |     return self._exec_single_context(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1988, in _exec_single_context
flask_app  |     self._handle_dbapi_exception(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2343, in _handle_dbapi_exception
flask_app  |     raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1969, in _exec_single_context
flask_app  |     self.dialect.do_execute(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 922, in do_execute
flask_app  |     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
flask_app  | sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "flight_db" does not exist
flask_app  | LINE 2: FROM flight_db ORDER BY flight_db."CREATEDDATE" DESC
flask_app  |              ^
flask_app  |
flask_app  | [SQL: SELECT flight_db.id AS flight_db_id, flight_db."DRP_DATETIME" AS "flight_db_DRP_DATETIME", flight_db."ARR_DATETIME" AS "flight_db_ARR_DATETIME", flight_db."DEP_AIRPORT" AS "flight_db_DEP_AIRPORT", flight_db."ARR_AIRPORT" AS "flight_db_ARR_AIRPORT", flight_db."AIRLINE" AS "flight_db_AIRLINE", flight_db."FLIGHTNUMBER" AS "flight_db_FLIGHTNUMBER", flight_db."PRICE" AS "flight_db_PRICE", flight_db."LINK" AS "flight_db_LINK", flight_db."CREATEDDATE" AS "flight_db_CREATEDDATE"
flask_app  | FROM flight_db ORDER BY flight_db."CREATEDDATE" DESC]
flask_app  | (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405)
flask_app  | [2023-12-30 21:08:21,619] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
flask_app  | Traceback (most recent call last):
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1969, in _exec_single_context
flask_app  |     self.dialect.do_execute(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 922, in do_execute
flask_app  |     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
flask_app  | psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "flight_db" does not exist
flask_app  | LINE 2: FROM flight_db ORDER BY flight_db."CREATEDDATE" DESC
flask_app  |              ^
flask_app  |
flask_app  |
flask_app  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
flask_app  |
flask_app  | Traceback (most recent call last):
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app
flask_app  |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request
flask_app  |     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 176, in wrapped_function
flask_app  |     return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
flask_app  |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
flask_app  |     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
flask_app  |   File "/app/app.py", line 258, in index
flask_app  |     posts = FlightDB.query.order_by(FlightDB.CREATEDDATE.desc()).all()
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2693, in all
flask_app  |     return self._iter().all()  # type: ignore
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2847, in _iter
flask_app  |     result: Union[ScalarResult[_T], Result[_T]] = self.session.execute(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2308, in execute
flask_app  |     return self._execute_internal(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2190, in _execute_internal
flask_app  |     result: Result[Any] = compile_state_cls.orm_execute_statement(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/context.py", line 293, in orm_execute_statement
flask_app  |     result = conn.execute(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1416, in execute
flask_app  |     return meth(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 516, in _execute_on_connection
flask_app  |     return connection._execute_clauseelement(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1639, in _execute_clauseelement
flask_app  |     ret = self._execute_context(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1848, in _execute_context
flask_app  |     return self._exec_single_context(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1988, in _exec_single_context
flask_app  |     self._handle_dbapi_exception(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2343, in _handle_dbapi_exception
flask_app  |     raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1969, in _exec_single_context
flask_app  |     self.dialect.do_execute(
flask_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 922, in do_execute
flask_app  |     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
flask_app  | sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "flight_db" does not exist
flask_app  | LINE 2: FROM flight_db ORDER BY flight_db."CREATEDDATE" DESC
flask_app  |              ^
flask_app  |
flask_app  | [SQL: SELECT ***
flask_app  | FROM flight_db ORDER BY flight_db."CREATEDDATE" DESC]
flask_app  | (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405)
flask_app  | [2023-12-30 21:08:52 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:6)
flask_app  | [2023-12-30 21:08:52 +0000] [6] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 6)
flask_app  | [2023-12-30 21:08:52 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:6) exited with code 1
flask_app  | [2023-12-30 21:08:52 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:6) exited with code 1.
flask_app  | [2023-12-30 21:08:52 +0000] [290] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 290
```

Answer (score 0):

> psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "flight_db" does not exist

It looks like the database was found but it didn't have any tables in it.  In the example you linked they call `db.create_all()` to create the tables.  I don't see that in your app code.  Is that getting called?

Comment: Thanks @Ian. I added these but still errored:from models import FlightDB,db
db.init_app(app)
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()